# Differentiator (Op amp) with a square wave

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, orcad, differential-amplifier

I'm working on a differentiator (op amp) with a unitary gain i calculated the value of RC and the period with a frequency of (1kHz).

[image]

*Figure 1. Differentiator Schematic (OrCAD).*

This is the schematic that im working and this is the graphic of that schematic.

[image]
*Figure 2. Graphic of differentiator schematic.*

I have the problem that the graphic is not right.

[image: Differentiator circuit of Texas Instruments]

*Figure 3. Differentiator circuit of Texas Instruments. Source: 
[Analog Engineer's Circuit: Amplifiers SBOA276–February 2018 Differentiator Circuit](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa276/sboa276.pdf).*

[image]

*Figure 4. Simulation profile.*

Comment: Please add a caption to each image so we know what they are. e.g., Figure 1. Differentiator schematic. Figure 2. Simulation output. Figure 3. ?????? Where did it come from?

Comment: What do you expect the derivative of a square wave to be?The derivative of an edge is spike - the gradient is very large (infinite in the limit). Given real components, the graph will be slightly diluted in terms of the sharp edges.

Comment: @Chu how can i make the pulse? or why my simulation is wrong?

Comment: Your simulation isn't wrong - what do you think the graph should look like? A pure differentiator is not a good idea.

Comment: @ I expect that my graph look like the last graph (Fig_03) that the derivate of a square wave is a pulse.

Comment: OK. Edit the post to include the link to the circuit that generates your Figure 3. Then we can find the difference in the circuits.

Comment: @Transistor i edit the post with the link

Comment: your time constant is 10x that of the squarewave period (assuming I am reading the pulse generator setting correct... 1ms?)

Comment: @Juan: I fixed the link. (If you click the "edited X minutes ago" link you can see how to use the mark-up correctly.) There is help on the editor toolbar.

Comment: @JonRB Right the period is 10x the RC or the op amp

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Differentiator schematic from the datasheet.*

You left out some important bits!

- R3 and R4 have equal values. They form a potential divider and the voltage at the connection is V<sub>CC</sub>/2. Since V<sub>CC</sub> is 5 V then the reference voltage is 2.5 V or mid-supply. C2 holds this voltage steady if the 5 V supply is noisy for any reason.
- Applying the bias to U1 non-inverting (+) input causes the output to stabilise at 2.5 V. Now it can swing above and below 2.5 V depending on the polarity of the pulses.
- The average voltage on your Figure 3 is (3.16 + 1.84)/2 = 2.5 V.

Comment: I chance the values of R3 and R4 but i simulated and isn't working yet.

Comment: Your simulator squarewave is 40 µs but Figure 2 only has a data point every 200 ms. Is your simulation speed correct?

Comment: The period T is 1 /Frequency is about 0.04m and the simulation profile is 250 ms is like the Figure 3.

Comment: Should the simulation profile be much faster than 40 µs? Should it be < 1 µs so that you get enough data points?

Comment: I dont get it, the period of the signal is 40 us but the run to time of the simulation is 200 ms? should be minor?

Comment: I am not familiar with Orcad. What are the little squares on Figure 2 every 200 ms on the traces? If they are the simulation calculation points then they are too far apart. Does the simulator have a setting for how many calculations per second of the X-axis?

Comment: After 40 s into [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwSseZy3nvM) the presenter sets the **step size** to 1 ms. What is your step size?

Comment: Look, @Juanestebanhernandezalvarez, for the moment stop trying to think about this. Set your step size to 1 usec and run the simulation. Don't argue, just do it. Then we can talk about it.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I did but didn't work. I usually think that my RC time is not the right one but i chance the values or C and R but actually didn't work

Comment: @Transistor: The dots on the waveform are not the datapoints, its just waveform indicators(same function as the colors).(@WhatRoughBeast)